# How to find which type of arguments passed to function

Tags: perl

A subrotuine is getting hash ref  :

```
sub test { 
  my $hash_ref = shift ; 

   if ( $hash_ref->{app} ) {
   ... 

   }
```

TheHash ref look like following format :  How to find out what type of data its has

```
#scallar
$hash {app} = 'app' ;
(or)
#array
$hash {app} = ['app1' ,'app2' ,'app3'];
(or)
#hash
$hash {app} = { app1 => { type => 1, contact=> abc }}
(or)
#array +hash 
$hash {app} = [{ app1 => { type => 1, contact=> abc }} ,
               { app2 => { type => 2, contact=> ded }}]
```

How to process this type of data strcture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash1 = {key => 'app',};
my $hash2 = {key => ['app1', 'app2'],};
my $hash3 = {key => {app1 => {type => 1, contact => 'abc'}},};
my $hash4 = {key => [{app1 => {type => 1, contact => 'abc'}}, {app2 => {type => 2, contact => 'ded'}}],};
my %tests = (1 => $hash1, 2 => $hash2, 3 => $hash3, 4 => $hash4);

while (my ($test_nr, $test_hash) = each %tests) {
    if (!ref $test_hash->{key}) {
        print "test $test_nr is scalar\n";
    } elsif (ref $test_hash->{key} eq 'HASH') {
        print "test $test_nr is hash ref\n";
    } elsif (ref $test_hash->{key} eq 'ARRAY') {
        if (ref $test_hash->{key}[0]) {
            print "test $test_nr is array of hash refs\n";
        } else {
            print "test $test_nr is array\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a reference you can check the type with [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html):

```
my %hash = ( app => ['app1' ,'app2' ,'app3'] );
print ref($hash{app}), "\n";
```

prints `ARRAY`.